# relationship between the derivative of a vector valued function and a scalar function of a real variable

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

Let's say we have function $f(x)=x$ and $F(x) = (x, x)$. The first one has derivative of $1$, and the second one has the derivative $(1, 1)$.

Are they related as follows: $F'$ is the direction vector of $f'$, and $f'$ is the ratio between the second and the first component of $F'$?

Does the magnitude of $F'$ mean anything?

Comment: I think you mean that $X'$ is the direction vector of $\color{red}{F}'\,.$ I do not want to comment about the relationship of $f$ and $F$ (or their deriivatives). Think of $x$ as time and $x\mapsto F(x)=(x,x)$ or more generally $x\mapsto (F_1(x),F_2(x))$ as the trajectory of a particle in $\mathbb R^2\,.$ In which direction does the particle travel? And what is its speed?

Comment: @KurtG. Yes, I made a typo, $X'$ should have been $F'$. I understand in your questions the direction would be $F'$, and the speed would be $\|F'\|$, but I'm really trying to understand if there is any relation between $f$ and $F$. Seems the $f(x)$ is a function, and $F(x)$ is the graph of that function, but I'm not sure if we can make the derivative relationship in general (intuitively it should be possible, because they seem to be just different notations for the same thing, but I'm not sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To offer some additional information about Kurt G's comment:

Think of $F$ as being a function of a different parameter $t$. Namely $$F(t) = (x(t), y(t))$$ where $x$ and $y$ are functions of $t$ themselves. Now suppose that there is some domain $D$ such that there is a unique value of $x(t)$ for each $t \in D$. That is, if $x(t_1) = x(t_2)$ then $t_1 = t_2$. With this, if we know what the value of $x$ is, we can figure out $t$ from it, and then calculate $y(t)$. This defines $y$ as a function of $x$, which gives us $y = f(x)$, and we can rewrite $F$ as
$$F(t) = \big(x(t), f(x(t))\big)$$

Now think of $F(t)$ as being the location of a moving particle at time $t$. $F'(t)$ is the *velocity* of that particle at time $t$. That is, the magnitude $\|F'(t)\|$ of $F'(t)$ is the speed at which the particle is moving, while the ratio $$\frac 1{\|F'(t)\|}F'(t)$$ is the unit vector giving the direction the particle is currently travelling.

Since $y(t) = f(x(t))$, we can use the chain rule to calculate $$y'(t) = f'(x(t))x'(t)$$ So $$f'(x(t)) = \frac{y'(t)}{x'(t)}$$
or in Leibniz notation:$$\frac{df}{dx} = \dfrac{\ \ \dfrac{dy}{dt}\ \ }{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}$$

This ratio is independent of the magnitude of $F'(t)$, and depends only on its direction.

In your particular example, we can choose $x$ to be any nice function of $t$, but $f(x) = x$, so $f'(x) = 1$ and we find that $$F'(t) = (x'(t), x'(t)) = x'(t)(1,1)$$
The magnitude (speed) is given by $$\|F'(t)\| = \sqrt{(x'(t))^2 + (x'(t))^2} = |x'(t)|\sqrt 2$$which will vary depending on what function of $t$ we selected for $x$, while the direction is $$\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}2, \frac{\sqrt 2}2\right),$$ a unit vector inclined at $45^\circ$ to the $x$-axis, i.e., pointing along the line $y = x = f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like my main confusion was that I implicitly considered $f'$ to be a vector as well, but it's actually just the slope of the direction vector, but the vector is $F'$ (not $f'$, as that one is a scalar value). I'm just not sure how you concluded "This ratio is independent of the magnitude of ′(), and depends only on its direction.", but I'm happy with the answer even without knowing that.

Comment: @S11n - If $v = (v_1, v_2)$ is a vector with magnitude $r = \sqrt{v_1^2 + v_2^2}$, then $$v = r(u_1, u_2)$$ where $u_1 = \frac{v_1}r, u_2 = \frac{v_2}r$. $u = (u_1, u_2)$ is a unit vector. Now the ratio of the $y$ to $x$ coordinates of $u$ are $$\dfrac{u_2}{u_1} = \dfrac{\frac{v_1}r}{\frac{v_2}r} = \dfrac{v_1}{v_2},$$ the same as for $v$. And this is true for any other vector $w$ pointing in the same direction as $u$ and $v$. This ratio - the slope - is the same for all vectors pointing in that direction, regardless of magnitude.

Comment: Yes, makes sense! Thanks!